# Some viewers also watch this youtube channel

Tags: youtube

I have watched YouTube without account (mobile app), and I saw this notification video below, I have no idea who is it, but now I know that he/she watches this channel

Could you please give some documentation about this feature

[image]

*Image was taken from [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/mrfreshasian/comments/cev1w2/muselk_viewers_also_watch_this_channel/) just to show how it looks*

Comment: I tried "using Google Chrome" enter to the video you posted as image - here's the [link](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=G56vQNL1OTk), but I can't see there the "X viewers also watch this channel", hence, I think this is only available on the mobile app. About how it is done, the few I read is about analytics are involved, but not code is provided in "YouTube Creator Academy" - sorry not be more helpful than this. I don't think that YouTUbe API is used for this since is not been updated from years.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave thanks for your response, I removed `api` tags

Comment: No problem, Yegor. Another suggestion is: if there's a way to check the requests made by the YouTube mobile app, you could check how you can get this information. Unfortunately, that's beyond my knowledge. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"(x) viewers also watched this video" is driven by YouTube analytics based on your personal 'history' list. The ONLY WAY to 'stop' these pop-ups (which now cover half of the thumbnail of the new video you wish to watch) is to completely clear your 'history' list.

There is no 'turn this feature on/off' button in settings that will work. I'm not sure WHY this is important to YouTube to push 'viewing' of other people's views...other than more 'herd mentality' social engineering at work...but...

There you go.